# How to enable Azure MFA for deploying web services?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, multi-factor-authentication

We've enabled multi-factor authentication for our Azure subscription and it seems to work fine when logging on to the portal, but when I try to deploy a web service from Visual Studio it just goes ahead and does it without so much as confirming my password.

This is completely unacceptable for us, it must absolutely require prompting for both a password and an SMS code in order to able to deploy. Deploying something incorrectly, accidentally or without sufficient authorization has the potential to severely compromise the integrity of our service.

Comment: Why don't you use slots and swap for your web apps?

Comment: We do intend to do that, but even deploying to a staging slot should require MFA, and certainly doing the swap should.

Comment: Are you saying that you can just login to your local box and deploy from Visual Studio to Azure directly? Does your local machine require MFA?

Comment: Not currently, but to protect against accidental deployment or a case where somebody else is using an authorised developer machine (with or without their knowledge) we need the act of deployment to require re-authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure Visual Studio on the developer machine to connect to Azure subscription, did you uncheck "Remember Password" for login screen and "Trust this computer"?

Secondly, you can provide the developer only Read permission on the underlying artifact (i.e. Web App or Cloud Service) using the Role-Based Access Control (RBAC). To deploy, they would have to [use deployment credentials](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rbac-and-azure-websites-publishing/).